# Modify a text file on IIS

Tags: iis

How can I let a client modify a file on my server directly through IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you use client-side browser to access the text file in the server, it will use staicfile hanlder instead of other handler.

The staticfile handler doesn't contain any method which allow client side modify the server's text file. Details about how it work, you could refer to this [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/StaticFileHandler.cs). It only contains the SendFile method which is used to send the file content to the client-side.

If you want to let the client side modify the text file, you should use some other technology like asp.net to achieve your requirement.